# Replying to the original tweeter in a retweet in TweetCaster?

Tags: twitter, tweetcaster

If a friend retweets something nad I attempt to 'reply' to it tweetcaser only shows my friend who retweeted the item as a recipient in the @ thing, is it possible for me to be able to see the original tweet username @ as well so my reply goes to both?

Answer (score 4):

Some Twitter apps allow you to "retweet with comment" or "quote & reply" in which case you can remove the original username before retweeting.  If your friend chose to do that before retweeting, you won't be able to see the original username.

[TweetCaster Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handmark.tweetcaster.premium) has the "retweet with comment" option.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the latter on Google Play?

Comment: TweetCaster Pro for Twitter on Google Play https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handmark.tweetcaster.premium

Comment: You can *edit* your answers, any time, to improve them. Thanks for the link, I added it into your answer!